# Visit / click counter on an website based only on JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a counter for a website that is designed and created only with HTML+CSS and Javascript as back-end.
I know that JS is a client-side scripting language, and it doesn't run on the server, and so is HTML. The application is deployed on a WebLogic server.
I would need to create any sort of counter that can show how many times was the website visited by all the users. Is there a way to create this without using PHP?

Comment: Hit counters disappeared years ago, but if you still want one then a cursory Google search will turn up a load of services that provide them. You just need to do some research.

Comment: First off, no, JavaScript is not "a client-side scripting language." It's used in lots of environments -- in web browsers, on web servers, in non-web applications, etc. Secondly: Yes, of course you can develop this without using PHP -- use a different server-side technology. Given that the application runs on a WebLogic server, Java would seem like the obvious choice. Or you could use JavaScript via Rhino or Nashorn.  But finally: Hit tracking is something best done by the web server software and analysis tools that run on its log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to have any server on a backend. If you use NodeJS as a server you can use a gist like this https://gist.github.com/hubgit/399898 and some modify it to send count value to user.